# How to integrate On-Premises Microsoft Dynamic Navision oauth client Web services link in SharePoint o365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, dynamics-crm

How to use On-Premises Microsoft Dynamic Navision Oauth client Web services link in SharePoint o365?

We have SharePoint o365 and Dynamic Navision 2016 (On-premise **not azure based**).
Now we are developing a expense Management system. some data sync Navision to SharePoint Online.
but we are facing integration issues SharePoint to Navision.
We have Navision oauth data  web services link, we don't have idea how to get data Navision to ShatePoint best way.
 We request all of you please suggest how to get the data Navision to SharePoint online.
can we get through SharePoint hosted app?
or 
Provider hosted Add-in?
Please  guide and support me which one is best and easy way and how to achieve this? 
 **condition**.
We don't have Azure subscription.
We have SharePoint E1 plan.
we have Navision 2016 version in own on-premises.

Please share some link if any useful for me.
Thanks in Advanced.